# How to set up dual monitor with Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and Nvidia Quadro K2200

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a problem with Dell Precision Tower 3620 with two Dell P2717H displays. Both are connected via DisplayPort-cables to Nvidia card.

I have a fresh clean install from Kubuntu 16.04.1, with which I have struggled for over 12 hours and just can't seem to manage get them working as dual monitors should.

Two graphic controllers are:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K2200] (rev a2)
```

The [most recent version](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) of (Linux 64-bit) driver is 367.35. I have installed it from repository:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

I have tried the tuning approaches mentioned in [NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver README and Installation Guide](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.35/README/index.html), with no success. (I have tried different naming for Monitors suspecting the DFP-3 and DFP-4 were reserved words but ended up using them because in the MetaModes the displays are identified as them anyways.)

xorg.conf:

```
# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: option, VertRefresh source: option
    Identifier     "DFP-3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL P2717H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: option, VertRefresh source: option
    Identifier     "DFP-4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL P2717H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"

#    Option      "TwinView"                 "true"
    Option      "RenderAccel"              "true"
    Option      "UseEdidFreqs"             "true"
    Option      "MetaModes"                "DFP-3: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-4: 1920x1080 +1920+0"


#    "DP-2: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0},
#     DP-3: 1920x1080 @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"


#    Option      "SecondMonitorHorizSync"   "30.0-83.0"
#    Option      "SecondMonitorVertRefresh" "56.0-76.0"

    BoardName      "Quadro K2200"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"

#    Option      "TwinView"                 "true"
    Option      "RenderAccel"              "true"
    Option      "UseEdidFreqs"             "true"
    Option      "MetaModes"                "DFP-3: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-4: 1920x1080 +1920+0"

    Option "MetaModeOrientation"      "DFP-4 LeftOf DFP-3"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor"         "DFP-4,DFP-3"

#    Option      "SecondMonitorHorizSync"   "30.0-83.0"
#    Option      "SecondMonitorVertRefresh" "56.0-76.0"

    BoardName      "Quadro K2200"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
         Identifier   "Screen3"
         Device       "nvidia3"
         Monitor      "DFP-3"
         DefaultDepth 24
         SubSection "Display"
           Viewport   0 0
           Depth      24
#           Modes      "3840x1080" "2560x1024" "1024x768" "1600x600" "1280x480"
           Modes      "1920x1080"
         EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
         Identifier   "Screen4"
         Device       "nvidia4"
         Monitor      "DFP-4"
         DefaultDepth 24
         SubSection "Display"
           Viewport   0 1
           Depth      24
           Modes      "1920x1080"
         EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Multihead"
    Screen 0 "Screen3" 0 0
    Screen 1 "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
#    Option "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection
```

The Xorg.0.log:

```
[   504.073] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-4431.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[   504.073] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[   504.073] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   504.073] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   504.073] Current Operating System: Linux simson 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64
[   504.073] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03ea436e-d69b-4c1a-aab7-ac75aeabeea3 ro
[   504.073] Build Date: 22 July 2016  07:50:34AM
[   504.073] xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   504.073] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[   504.073]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   504.074] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   504.074] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 18 18:09:06 2016
[   504.074] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   504.074] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   504.074] (==) ServerLayout "Multihead"
[   504.074] (**) |-->Screen "Screen3" (0)
[   504.074] (**) |   |-->Monitor "DFP-3"
[   504.074] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia3"
[   504.074] (**) |-->Screen "Screen4" (1)
[   504.074] (**) |   |-->Monitor "DFP-4"
[   504.074] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia4"
[   504.074] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   504.074] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   504.074] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   504.074] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   504.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   504.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   504.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   504.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   504.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   504.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   504.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   504.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   504.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   504.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   504.074] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   504.074] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   504.074] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   504.074] (II) Loader magic: 0x558663880da0
[   504.074] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   504.074]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   504.074]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[   504.074]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[   504.074]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[   504.075] (++) using VT number 7

[   504.075] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   504.075] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   504.075] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   504.076] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:1912:1028:06b7 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf5000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[   504.076] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:13ba:10de:1097 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   504.076] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[   504.076] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   504.076] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   504.076] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[   504.079] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   504.079]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   504.079]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   504.079] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  367.35  Mon Jul 11 22:39:07 PDT 2016
[   504.079] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   504.079] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[   504.079] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   504.079]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   504.079]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   504.079] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  367.35  Mon Jul 11 22:14:48 PDT 2016
[   504.079] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   504.082] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   504.082] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   504.082] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   504.082] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   504.082]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   504.082]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   504.082] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   504.082] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   504.083] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   504.083] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   504.083]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   504.083]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   504.083] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   504.083] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   504.083] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   504.083] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   504.083] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   504.083] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "RenderAccel" "true"
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseEdidFreqs" "true"
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling RENDER acceleration
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "DFP-3: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-4: 1920x1080 +1920+0"
[   504.083] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[   504.547] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4 (boot)
[   504.550] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: disconnected
[   504.550] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.550] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.552] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: disconnected
[   504.552] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[   504.552] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.552] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.553] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   504.553] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   504.553] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.553] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): connected
[   504.554] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): connected
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): Internal DisplayPort
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): 
[   504.556] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro K2200 (GM107GL-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[   504.556] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 4194304 kBytes
[   504.556] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.7a.00.1c
[   504.556] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[   504.556] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   504.556] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DELL P2717H (DFP-3) (Using EDID frequencies has
[   504.556] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[   504.557] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   504.557] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DELL P2717H (DFP-4) (Using EDID frequencies has
[   504.557] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[   504.558] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[   504.558] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-3:1920x1080+0+0,DFP-4:1920x1080+1920+0"
[   504.558] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3840 x 1080
[   504.562] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (81, 80); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[   504.562] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[   504.562] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   504.563] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[   504.563] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[   504.578] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-3:1920x1080+0+0,DFP-4:1920x1080+1920+0"
[   504.775] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   504.775] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[   504.775] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   504.775] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   504.775] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   504.775] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   504.775] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   504.775] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   504.775] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   504.775] (--) RandR disabled
[   504.777] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   504.778] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   504.778] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[   504.799] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   504.799] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   504.799] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   504.799] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   504.799] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   504.799]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.10.1
[   504.799]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   504.799]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[   504.799] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   504.799] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   504.799] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   504.799] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   504.799] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   504.799] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   504.799] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   504.799] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   504.799] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   504.799] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   504.799] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fi"
[   504.808] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[   504.808] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   504.808] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[   504.808] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   504.808] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[   504.808] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   504.808] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[   504.808] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[   504.808] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6/event3"
[   504.808] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fi"
[   504.808] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   504.808] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   504.808] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   504.808] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   504.808] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   504.808] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   504.808] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   504.808] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   504.808] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[   504.808] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   504.808] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fi"
[   504.808] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   504.808] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   504.808] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[   504.808] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[   504.808] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[   504.808] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[   504.809] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[   504.809] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   504.809] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[   504.809] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   504.809] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   504.809] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   504.809] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fi"
[   504.809] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event15)
[   504.809] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   504.809] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   504.809] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event16)
[   504.809] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   504.809] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   504.809] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event17)
[   504.809] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   504.809] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): connected
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): connected
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): Internal DisplayPort
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   504.882] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.458] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[   505.458] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.458] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.461] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[   505.461] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[   505.461] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.461] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.462] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   505.462] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   505.462] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.462] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): connected
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): connected
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): Internal DisplayPort
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   505.463] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   505.600] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-2: 1920x1080 @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[   506.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[   506.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   506.175] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[   506.175] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[   506.175] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.175] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   506.176] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   506.176] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   506.176] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.176] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): connected
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-3): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): connected
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): Internal DisplayPort
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL P2717H (DFP-4): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   506.177] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

As stated before, I have tried several things such as working with only one xorg.conf'd Device and using the TwinView. At best I came up with both monitors showing correctly (one huge desktop with the K-logo in center) as the X was starting, but then ended up with screens with cursor and nothing more (no panels, no desktop image, just cursor which moved nicely across two screens, though).

Second approach was to start from the nvidia-settings. The nvidia-settings starts with one screen visible. Drop down menu has three items: X screen 0, DELL P2717H (DFP-3), DELL P2717H (DFP-4). I have tried to add second screen (X screen 1) and then setting the DFP-3 and 4 to them. Then saving the xorg.conf output and restarting, I came up with setting with one screen ok and other having just X cursor. Others have reported such behaviour, but any fixes I found did not work. (Due to lack of points cannot put any referring links here.)

The X output log which I gave is the result of googling and getting rid of different warnings and errors. It detects the both displays and even calculates the virtual size of the desktop correctly, but it just won't work. :-(

The weird thing is that the System settings > Display Configuration does not allow the dual screens to show: I can select the Primary display from DP-3 and DP-2, but only one screen is shown at a time. (Some reported that re-clicking the enabled box solved some problem, but that did not work with me).

I wonder how the X log showed the DFP-3 and DFP-4 and X configuration DP-2 and DP-3. This might have nothing to do with problem, but then why does X log have:

```
[   505.600] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-2: 1920x1080 @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
```

I tried to add MetaMode for DP-2 and DP-3, but that did not help either.

I have also tried different versions of nvidia driver, but still no go with the dual displays.

I must use Windows for working purposes and the Win 10 Pro handles the displays smoothly. One reason for selecting the Dell was the (seeminly) good support it had for *nix. I'll just hope I could get displays going with Kubuntu too.

Any help and/or pointers is most highly appreciated!

**EDIT 22.8.2016:**

*Now I have a working setup, so here's the catch up from couple of days.*

I played with X packages and thanks to typo and console connection with no-history I finally ended up with so badly broken dependencies that my best option was to re-install the Kubuntu. That was easy decision as I hadn't gone to data migration from old system.

After re-installing the Kubuntu, the both displays were correctly detected without the nvidia driver (now as DP-1 and DP-2).

I wondered why it now succeeded, and then remembered that prior trying the nvidia from PPA repository, I manually tried to install the driver via Nvidia script, which failed. **The original Nvidia install script must have therefore broken something.**

Finally, I decided to test how the Ubuntu 16.04.01 would handle it. After clean install, both displays were correctly identified.

I decided to proceed with data migration from old PC via Ubuntu.

However, the whole system halted several times, which required a PC reset. Usually the X just froze, but mouse cursor was still movable.

I installed the `nvidia driver 361.42` by:

1. Entering the `Software & Updates` from Ubuntu menu and from there the
2. Additional Drivers tab identified the card `NVIDIA Corporation: GM107GL [Quadro K2200]`
3. Selecting the topmost item: Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 (proprietary, tested)
4. After the installation finished, rebooted the system

So far everything had worked smoothly with no system halts. :)